# How to do auto scaling inline svg without height in IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, svg, inline-svg

## Mark-up, styling

*HTML*

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50">
    <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" />
</svg>
```

*CSS*

```
svg { width:50px; border:1px solid red; }
```

*example URL*

https://jsfiddle.net/rfjmanuf/

## Result

*Firefox 58, Chrome 64*

[image]

*IE 11*

[image]

## Problem

I want to know how to render in IE like other browsers?
Thank you for reading.

Comment: Been through https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/ already?

Answer (score -3):

Give `width` and `height` same as `viewBox` last 2 value. 1st is `width` and 2nd is `height`. Because SVG doesn't scale as it should.

Try this:

```
<svg width="50px" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
    <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" />
</svg>
```

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rfjmanuf/1/)

Comment: setting a fixed height/width causes responsive scaling problems